# Is there a way to access the parameter used inside route() in ktor

Tags: routes, url-routing, ktor

As per [Ktor documentation](https://ktor.io/docs/routing-in-ktor.html#path_parameter), we can access the path parameters in routes using `call.paramters["params"]` as given below,

```
get("/user/{login}") {
    if (call.parameters["login"] == "admin") {
        // ...
    }
}
```

However when we use nesting routing for example,

```
routing {
    route("/order") {
        route("/shipment/{param1}") { 
               ----------need param1 here---------------
            get("/sample/{param2}") {

            }
            post("/sample/{param2}") {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

here we can access both param2 and param3 using the above method. Param1 is treated as a string itself in the URL. Is there a way to access param1 before going to the get and post methods( as mentioned in the code)?

Answer (score 0):

You can access both `param1` and `param2` in `get("/sample/{param2}")` and `post("/sample/{param2}")` routes. If you want to access `param1` in the `route("/shipment/{param1}")` route then you can call the `handle` method or add an HTTP method route:

```
route("/shipment/{param1}") {
    get {
        println(call.parameters["param1"])
    }

    handle { // handles any HTTP method
        println(call.parameters["param1"])
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: can you share any resources regarding this handle method? I can't find one.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is only a short description of it in API documentation https://api.ktor.io/ktor-server/ktor-server-core/io.ktor.server.routing/-route/handle.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use route scoped plugin , it's partially documented [here](https://ktor.io/docs/plugins.html#install-route) but here is an example

```kt
    route("/order") {
                route("/shipment/{param1}") {
                    install(createRouteScopedPlugin("pluginName"){
                        on(CallSetup) { call ->
                            val param = call.parameters["param1"]
                        }
                    })
                    get("/sample/{param2}") {

                    }
                    post("/sample/{param2}") {

                    }
                }
            }
```